# 2 EditText vertically, soft keyboard cover the below one when the up one selected

Tags: android-softkeyboard

I want both EditTexts showed above the soft keyboard if the upper one selected and input, the below one can show according to the changes in the upper one without covered by soft keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Set the android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize, so your app is resized above the keyboard rather than covered.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have been using that setting, but the issue is that when I click the upper one, the keyboard show just under the upper one, so the lower one is covered. Of course when I click the lower one, both of them can be displayed.

Comment: I need to display those 2 EditText at the same time when input , so the result can be displayed timely